# Nginx : File Not found inside directory ( though file exists ) .. On Root directory it works fine

Tags: nginx

On my server I have few files in /var/www and few in /var/www/static ..

> `wget http://localhost/static/404.html`

etc. works fine.

If I create a new file suppose test.html in /var/www

> wget http://localhost/test.html

works fine.

If I create a new file suppose test.html in /var/www/static
`wget http://localhost/static/test.html` NOT WORKS FINE.

I tried restarting nginx; nginx access logs just says 404. Any clue !

default file in sites-enabled:

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8080;

    # maximum number of idle connections to each upstream server
    keepalive 20;
}

map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_scheme {
    default $scheme;
    https   https;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /var/www;
    resolver     10.0.0.2;

    ssl_certificate          cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key      private-key.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout      5m;

    ssl_protocols                TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers    on;

    set $mweb false;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
        set $mweb true;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-)") {
        set $mweb true;
    }
    if ($http_host = "crm.qa.hopscotch.in") {
        set $mweb false;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ 'desktop_site=true') {
        set $mweb false;
    }

    location / {
        if ($http_host = "qa.hopscotch.in") {
            rewrite ^ $proxy_scheme://www.qa.hopscotch.in$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto   $proxy_scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host:$server_port;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Connection          "";

        if ($mweb = true) {
            set $mweb_elb        "$proxy_scheme://m.qa.hopscotch.in";
            proxy_pass           $mweb_elb;
            break;
        }

        proxy_pass              http://backend;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status   on;
        access_log    off;
        allow         127.0.0.1;
        deny          all;
    }
}
```

Comment: You proxy all requests to backend. Nginx do not serve these files.

Comment: what should I change to make this work ! Also, then how are URLs like wget http://localhost/static/404.html working fine .. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your requests are proxied to localhost at port 8080 - whatever runs there decides what to serve. A simple location block to just serve any files it finds in the directory would be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

This will return a file if it is found, or a http 404 error if the file could not be found.

By the way, using so many if statements is maybe not a good idea, because it hurts nginx performance. I have never used an if statement in my configs, because it is usually not worth it and also discouraged by nginx documentation.

Comment: `try_files $uri =404;` is meaningless in a location which serves static files, just an empty `location / {}` would do the same.

Comment: You are right, but I prefer an explicit `try_files $uri =404;` - it makes it easier to understand what is going on, and it is easy to expand, usually for adding a fastcgi upstream or proxy, or just to set a default error page instead of the default 404 error.

Comment: As a developer, I consider "explicit" `try_files` to be a clear indication of misunderstanding of how requests are handled and a bad thing (not even talking about unneeded work being done). Moreover, it will prevent various things from working correctly - serving directory indexes, proxying to remote servers and so on, thus preventing expansion of a configuration. As for changing error pages, it should be done with `error_page` instead.

Comment: It is the opposite - for proxying or fastcgi `try_files` is exactly the right thing, for example with `try_files $uri @php;` and an additional @php block. That way static files are delivered from the file system and all other requests are handled by a PHP front controller. That's usually what you want nowadays. And for somebody who is new to Nginx, `try_files` is easy to understand and often useful.

Comment: For proxying and fastcgi `try_files` is an _additional_ thing which is either right (checks if the file exists, may be useful with local php) or completely wrong (e.g., if the request is proxied to a backend server, and no files exists on the frontend server with nginx; or if the request uses `fastcgi_split_pathinfo`). Using it "to make it easier to understand" is a wrong approach and will only work with trivial configurations. YMMV.